# camel activemq component and customproccessor

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a queue from which I want to consume messages in a concurrent way then passing these messages to MyProcessor with implement org.apache.camel.Processor, I want MyProcessor to run in a parallel way too. notice that MyProcessor invoke a runnable with a reantrantlock.

```
from(activemq:Myqueue?maxConcurrentConsumers=10)
   .process(new MyProcessor());

class MyProcessor implements org.apache.camel.Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                      // Do some process

                      sleep(1000)

        }
    }
```

Is it gonna run on parallel fashion ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can configure the Camel JMS / ActiveMQ endpoint to use concurrent consumers, then the Camel rotue will process messages in parallel

```
from("activemq:Myqueue?concurrentConsumers=5&maxConcurrentConsumers=10")
    .process(new MyProcessor());
```

The endpoint has 2 options to set a range for concurrent consumers. In the code above we have 5-10 as the range.

See more details at: http://camel.apache.org/jms